# Check for a specific value in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to retrieve the value in A if the value of B is 1. But the below code throws the error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"

```
    A   B
0   a1  18
1   b1  25229
2   c2  2
3   d3  12
4   e4  1
```

Code:

```
for a,b in df7.iteritems():
  if (df7['b'] == 1):
    print (df7['a'])
```

Comment: Try `df7.loc[df7.b.eq(1), 'A']`?

Comment: df.loc[df.B==1,'A']

Comment: You wouldn't do `for a,b in df7.iteritems():` and then try to reference the columns by `df7['a']`, `df7['b']`, that will return you the entire column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a simple comparison like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a1', 'b1', 'c2', 'd3', 'e4'], 'B': [18, 25229, 2, 12, 1]})
print(df[df['B'] == 1]['A'])
```

Which yields

```
4    e4
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: how would I just get e4 and not '4'?

Answer (score 0):

Another simple code would be

```
df7[df7['b'] == 1]['a']
```

will give a dataframe of column a where b=1.